# Crome Browser says "Notification/Camera/Microphone Blocked to protect your privacy"

Tags: angular, angularjs, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

1. type url **chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure**
2. Enter url in the textarea
3. Choose Enabled in the select option
4. Relunch the browser
5. again run the url in address bar

I try to explain how can we enabled notification in not secured urls.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.